# Error message Not Disappearing

Tags: visualforce

We display error message in vf when some action is performed using a command link and through apex:messages.
But the problem we get is "after error message is displayed the next time when i try to perform some different action using the same command link, i am still getting the same error message which was displayed previously and command link doesn do the required action.

can some one please help me on this ?

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:messages id="error" /> 
<apex:commandlink action="{!submitAction}" styleClass="blueButton" value="Submit" >
```

Controller:

```
public PageReference submitAction(){ 
     if(){ // } 
     else{ 
         ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Only Account members can be Account backup admin')); 
         getContactWrapperList(); 
         return NULL; 
      } 
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing some of the VF and controller code ? That will make it easier to spot to problem.

Comment: In My  VF page:

  <apex:messages id="error" />

 <apex:commandlink action="{!submitAction}"  styleClass="blueButton" value="Submit" >

Controller:
 public PageReference submitAction(){

if(){
//
}

else{
  ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error,'Only Account members can be Account backup admin')); 
               getContactWrapperList();  
                 return NULL;
}


}

Comment: When you say "the same commnadlink", do you mean another command link on your page, i assume so? Otherwise if the same condition causing the message the first time still exists the message will again be output. If its indeed another command link on the page, is it doing a partial page refresh perhaps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned